# What changes to make in admob code when game is released?

Tags: android, admob, cocos2d-x

Hey I followed this tutorial to add admob ads to my game:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/User_Tutorial-Integrate_AdMob

Now this is used to test ads on my device and works properly. When I release this app am I supposed to make any change to the following code or should I let it stay like this and it will work properly on all devices?

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice("HASH_DEVICE_ID") //actual device id here
.build();
```

Comment: No, you don't need to remove it. Your device should always be considered as the test device. On all other devices it will display the ads correctly.

Comment: My game has around 50 downloads but admob says that there are 0 users. It is however displaying 500 impressions. Should I be worried?

Comment: I would not be worried. If you see the number of impressions increasing, that's totally fine. You need to connect Google Analytics to your AdMob account to have these user stats...